# How to dynamically get the value of an object with a key that is stored in a variable

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have an object in Typescript, I am trying to dynamically change the string of the key. The below isn't working as expected. It throws the following Typescript error:

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type

```
'{ key1: string; key2: string; }'.
```

No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type

```
'{ key1: string; key2: string; }'.ts(7053)
```

```
let c:string='key2'
var o = { key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2' };
var val = o[c]; //should return 'value2'
```

And if I change the variable c to 'key1', it should return 'value1'.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps

```
var o = { key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2' };
let c: keyof typeof o = 'key2'
var val = o[c];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change dynamically key , you should create dynamic interface like below `[key: string]` is for dynamic key

```
<-------
interface Example {
   [key: string]: string
}
------->

var o: Example = { key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2' };
var val = o[c];
```